# Diferenciar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas dentro de un WHERE en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente `query`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_descriptores WHERE nombre = 'dulce';
```

El cual me trae los siguientes resultados:

```
_________________________________________________________________
|idDescriptor |idDescriptorPadre |nombre |name |colorhex | tipo |
_________________________________________________________________
|21           |270               |Dulce  |Sweet|DDA0DD   |2     |
_________________________________________________________________
|127          |0                 |DULCE  |SWEET|FCF9CC   |1     |
_________________________________________________________________
```

Quisiera saber como puedo realizar el `query` y que me *diferencie entre mayúsculas y minúsculas*, es decir: si mi *criterio* es **'dulce'** que no me traiga nada ya que no hay ningún registro en la tabla en donde la columna *nombre* sea llamada 'dulce', si mi criterio es **'Dulce'** que me traiga el registro con `idDescriptor 21` y si mi criterio es **'DULCE'** que me traiga el registro con el **idDescriptor 127** ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Necesitas usar el comando `BINARY`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_descriptores 
WHERE nombre = BINARY 'dulce';
```

Comment: Gracias, no pensé que algo tan sencillo fuese tan útil, no supe como buscar en inglés.

Comment: @Naos No hay problema, para eso está SO en español