# Operador exactamente igual en consulta SQL

Tags: mysql

Me gustaría hacer una consulta en `sql` de tal forma que busque en una tabla si coinciden los datos

La variable **email** no importa si no coinciden en mayúsculas y minúsculas

La variable **password** tiene que coincidir examentente mayúsculas y minúsculas

¿Hay algún operador como `===` para esta acción?

```html
$email = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['psw'];

$consulta = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE email = '$email' AND pass = '$password'");  

if(!$consulta){ 
    echo "<script>history.go(-1)</script>";
    echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
   
    exit;
}
```

Comment: El operador = busca una coincidencia exacta.. estas teniendo algun problema con el?

Comment: Si, al hacer un login, puedo iniciar mi sesión independientemente si pongo la contraseña en mayusculas o minusculas

Comment: Que falla con esta consulta?

Comment: Que no distingue entre mayusculas y minusculas, sirve para hacer un login y puedo hacerlo independientemente de las mayusculas que use

Comment: Revisa si esta respuesta te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44772/diferenciar-entre-may%C3%BAsculas-y-min%C3%BAsculas-dentro-de-un-where-en-mysql

Comment: A la perfección compañero